# Is complex integration needed when normalizing a wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

I have to find $\phi_0$ from following wave function in the momentum space:
\begin{equation}
\phi(k) = \phi_0 \text{exp}\bigg(-\frac{(k-k_0)^2}{2\kappa^2}\bigg)
\end{equation}
I know that I have to use the normaliazation criteria:
\begin{equation}
\lVert \phi(k) \rVert = 1
\end{equation}
With the $L^2$ Norm:
\begin{equation}
\lVert \phi(k) \rVert = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\phi(k)|^2 dk= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(k)^*\phi(k) dk
\end{equation}
However I'm unsure how to get $\phi(k)^*$. The problem doesn't state it explicitly, but I asume that $k_0, \kappa \in \mathbb{C}$.

So I'm thinking of splitting each variable into real and imaginary parts like $k_0 = k_0'+i k_0''$, and then doing some algebra to find the real and imaginary part of the exponent, but I feel like there should be an easier way.

Which leads me to my next question: Is the momentum $k$ a complex variable?

If so I would need to integrate over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of just $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is probably assuming that $k_0$ and $\kappa$ are real. And $k$ is always real, it's a momentum after all.

Comment: Would it be solveable if $k_0$ and $\kappa$ were complex?

Comment: Yes, it's just more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The only complex quantity you might have here is $\phi_0$ (which phase is irrelevant, by the way), so you only have to integrate
\begin{equation}
\lVert \phi(k) \rVert = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\phi(k)|^2 dk= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\phi_0|^2 \exp\bigg(-\frac{(k-k_0)^2}{\kappa^2}\bigg)\, dk .
\end{equation}
$k$, $k_0$ and $\kappa$ are momentums, as stated by @Javier, so they are real. No need to do complicated/weird stuff!